# Graphical Editing of constraint is very slow in Android Studio 2.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, constraints

I am using constraint layout for most of UI in android studio but designing it in graphical editor is very slow.
Applying constraint is very slow.

My laptop is good .i7 5th gen 16 gb ram and 500 ssd. i think there should be no performance limitations. the issue is in android studio.
how to increase performance of graphical editor . please help.

Also CPU usage goes up to 50% when using graphical editor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three things to look at to improve performance:

1. Increase VM Heap Size for Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#adjusting_heap_size
2. Toggle the design surface to only blueprint mode: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html#change-appearance
3. Make sure you using the latest version of the Constraint Layout library v1.0.2: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/03/constraintlayout-102-is-now-available.html